# Help me please, my transaction is still unconfirmed

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Please help me, I have a payment which is not confirmed after 16 hours.

https://blockchain.info/tx/b10e78862f253c967ad588a7e017d75fc8fe85419e3f2506bfb790ddd765712c

What should I do?